# Custom Errors from a File

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read a file when ever an error occurs within my scripts so I can throw a custom error page.

When using ob_start/set_error_handler I am unable to use file_get_contents or ob_start within the callback to get the contents of my error template.

Does anyone know how I can output my custom template (and using eval) within the callback?

---

Edit: Some code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

function fatal_error_handler($buffer) {
  if (ereg("(error</b>:)(.+)(<br)", $buffer, $regs) ) {
    $ErrorString = preg_replace("/<.*?>/","",$regs[2]);
    error_log($ErrorString);

    $template = file_get_contents(sprintf('%s/errors/Error.php', TEMPLATES));
    return eval(sprintf('?>%s<?', $template);
    //return "ERROR CAUGHT check log file";
  }
  return $buffer;
}

function handle_error ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile on line $errline");
    if($errno == FATAL || $errno == ERROR){
        ob_end_flush();
        echo "ERROR CAUGHT check log file";
        exit(0);
    }
}

ob_start("fatal_error_handler");
set_error_handler("handle_error");
```

The above just displays an empty page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

function fatal_error_handler($buffer) {
  if (ereg("(error</b>:)(.+)(<br)", $buffer, $regs) ) {
    $ErrorString = preg_replace("/<.*?>/","",$regs[2]);
    error_log($ErrorString);

    ob_start();
    include(sprintf('%s/errors/Error.php', TEMPLATES));
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return eval(sprintf('?>%s<?', $template));
    //return "ERROR CAUGHT check log file";
  }
  return $buffer;
}

function handle_error ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile on line $errline");
    if($errno == FATAL || $errno == ERROR){
        ob_end_flush();
        echo "ERROR CAUGHT check log file";
        exit(0);
    }
}

ob_start("fatal_error_handler");
set_error_handler("handle_error");
```

and the above gives the following:

```
Fatal error: ob_start() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /var/www/index.php on line 16
```

Comment: Code examples always welcome to clarify what you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to :

- know that [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns false when it encounters an error.

  - which means you can test its return value,
  - and if it returned `false`, you can display your template
- also be careful : when there's a problem, it generates an error, and you don't want that one displayed

  - this is the kind of situation for which you can use the [@ operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php),
  - to "mask" the error -- you test if it returned false, anyway

It would give that kind of code :

```
$result = @file_get_contents('non-existing-file');
if ($result === false) {
    echo "An error has occured";
}
```

Which, in my case, displays :

```
An error has occured
```

Now, up to you to display your error template, depending on the Framework you might be using and all that ;-)

Comment: Pascal, thanks for replying... The file i'm trying to access exists and i've checked the path by simply returning the file path instead of the template. 

It seems file_get_contents is throwing an error that I cannot see, although I don't see it being related to the locate of the file.

I am passing in the full path of the file to file_get_contents rather then just the actual filename so the CWD issue can't be at fault.

Any other idea's would be greatfully appreciated!